# Best approach to incremently update application data

Tags: c#, database, caching, dynamic, storage

I have been working on an application for a couple of years that I updated using a back-end database. The whole key is that everything is cached on the client, so that it never requires an network connection to operate, but when it does have a connection it will always pickup the latest updates. Every application updated is shipped with the latest version of the database and I wanted it to download only the minimum amount of data when the database has been updated.

I currently use a table with a timestamp to check for updates. It looks something like this.

```
ID - Name - Description- Severity - LastUpdated
0 - test.exe - KnownVirus - Critical - 2009-09-11 13:38
1 - test2.exe - Firewall - None - 2009-09-12 14:38
```

This approach was fine for what I previously needed, but I am looking to expand more function of the application to use this type of dynamic approach. All the data is currently stored as `XML`, but I do not want to store complete XML files in the database and only transmit changed data.

So how would you go about allowing a fairly simple approach to storing dynamic content (text/xml/json/xaml) in a database, and have the client only download new updates? I was thinking of having logic that can handle XML inserted directly

```
ID - Data - Revision
15 - XXX - 15
```

`XXX` would be something like `<Content><File>Test.dll<File/><Description>New DLL to load.</Description></Content>` and would be inserted into the cache, but this would obviously be complicated as I would need to load them in sequence.

Another approach that has been mentioned was to base it on something similar to Source Control, storing the version in the root of the file and calculating the delta to figure out the minimal amount of data that need to be sent to the client.

Anyone got any suggestions on how to approach this with no risk for data corruption? I would also to expand with features that allows me to revert possibly bad revisions, and replace them with new working ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends on the tools you are using and the architecture you already have. Is there already a server with some logic and a data access layer?

Dynamic approaches might get complicated, slow and limit the number of solutions. Why do you need a dynamic structure? Would it be feasible to just add data by using a name-value pair approach in a relational database? Static and uniform data structures are much easier to handle.

Before going into detail, you should consider the different scenarios.

- Items can be added
- Items can be changed
- Items can be removed (I assume)

Adding is not a big problem. The client needs to remember the last revision number it got from the server and you write a query which get everything since there.

Changing is basically the same. You should care about identification of the items. You need an unchangeable surrogate key, as it seems to be the ID you already have. (Guids may be useful here.)

Removing is tricky. You need to either flag items as deleted instead of actually removing them, or have a list of removed IDs with the revision number when they had been removed.

Storing the data in the client: Consider using a relational database like SQLite in the client. (It doesn't need installation, it is just storing in a file. Firefox for instance stores quite a lot in SQLite databases.) When using the same in the server, you can probably reuse some code. It is also transaction based, which helps to keep it consistent (rollback in case of error during synchronization).

XML - if you really need it - can be stored just as a string in the database.

When using an abstraction layer or ORM that supports SQLite (eg. NHibernate), you may also reuse some code even when there is another database used by the server. Note that the learning curve for such an ORM might be rather steep. If you don't know anything like this, it could be too much.

You don't need to force reuse of code in the client and server.

Synchronization itself shouldn't be very complicated. You have a revision number in the client and a last revision in the server. You get all new / changed and deleted items since then in the client and apply it to the local store. Update the local revision number. Commit. Done.

I would never update only a part of a revision, because then you can't really know what changed since the last synchronization. Because you do differential updates, it is essential to have a well defined state of the client.

Comment: This is pretty much what I am doing already, just taking it a bit further. I currently use a Web Service to provide as a back-end to provide logic and a data access layer. Based on your post I think I will simply build on that existing structure, and take some of information you provided to further improve upon that.

Answer (score 4):

I would go with a solution using [Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb821992.aspx).

Quote from Microsoft:

Microsoft Sync Framework is a comprehensive synchronization platform enabling collaboration and offline for applications, services and devices. Developers can build synchronization ecosystems that integrate any application, any data from any store using any protocol over any network. Sync Framework features technologies and tools that enable roaming, sharing, and taking data offline.

A key aspect of Sync Framework is the ability to create custom providers. Providers enable any data sources to participate in the Sync Framework synchronization process, allowing peer-to-peer synchronization to occur.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds interesting -- I'll look into it as a possible solution.

Answer (score 4):

I have just built an application pretty much exactly as you described.  I built it on top of the Microsoft Sync Framework that DjSol mentioned.

I use a C# front end application with a SqlCe database, and a SQL 2005 Server at the other end.

The following articles were extremely useful for me:

[Tutorial: Synchronizing SQL Server and SQL Server Compact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928494.aspx)

[Walkthrough: Creating a Sync service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg298975.aspx)

[Step by step N-tier configuration of Sync services for ADO.NET 2.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlblog/archive/2010/04/19/step-by-step-n-tier-configuration-of-sync-services-for-ado-net-2-0.aspx)

[How to Sync schema changed database using sync framework?](http://tuvianblog.com/2011/05/04/how-to-sync-schema-changed-database-using-sync-framework/)

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what your back-end database is, but if it's SQL Server you can use SqlCE (SQL Server Compact Edition) as the client DB and then use RDA merge replication to update the client DB as desired. This will handle all your requirements for sure; there is no need to reinvent the wheel for such a common requirement.

Comment: I use MySQL at the moment, but I am more than open to other options.

Comment: I haven't used MySQL much, but apparently it does support one-way replication, which means it would work for your purposes as long as you could use MySQL instances in your client app as well as for the backend (I don't know if MySQL DBs can be distributed as a single client file or not). SQL Server + SqlCE would be perfect for you, except that you would need a license for the backend DB.

Comment: Thanks @MusiGenesis. I will consider changing to such a solution next time we update do a major overhaul of the complete system.